# creating a set in ssas that can store keys based on a predicate

Tags: mdx

I need to write a calculation in SSAS that can store keys within it based on calendar year. Equivalent sql query is:

```
select distinct personID 
from dbo.FactSales 
where OrderDateTimeBase >= 20160101
```

In the cube i have the Dim Customer table, Fact Sales and OrderDateTimeBase as a role playing dimension

Comment: what mdx have you tried?

Comment: what is a role playing dimension? I've seen them mentioned before but unsure what they are - how do they differ from user hierarchies or attribute hierarchies?

Comment: I've tried `( [Dim Person].[Person ID].[Person ID].MEMBERS, [Order Date Time Base].[Calendar Year].&[2016] )` i expected to see the list of personID that ordered in the year 2016 but it shows a null cause its in a calculated member, and i dont have a clue how to make a set of this. And role playing dim is when there are multiple relationships between a dim (date) and a fact(sales) table, and in ssas you can see those column names as a separate dim. so the DimDate plays several roles for fact table.